# How to round down to the nearest 50?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to round down to the nearest multiple of 50 in Excel.

So if cell A1 = 318, I want to round it down in cell B1 to 300, and if A1 = 367, round down to 350.

Is this possible?

If so how?

Comment: that's right, down to nearest 50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rounding functions work at the place level. You could use:

```
=50*INT(A1/50)
```

However, Ron Rosenfeld's answer is simpler.

If you wanted to **round** to a multiple instead of rounding down, you could use MROUND:

```
=MROUND(A1,50)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the `FLOOR` function

```
=FLOOR(A1,50)
```